# Why is the residue of $\frac{1}{z-w}R(z)$ at $w$ not continuous as a function of $w$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $R(z)$ be some fixed rational function, and define $Res_R(w)$ to be the residue of $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z-w}R(z)$ for any $w\in\mathbb{C}$.  I would have thought that $Res_R$ would be continuous in $w$, because it seems like the entries of the Laurent series of $\dfrac{1}{z-w}R(z)$ centered at $w$ should be continuous at $w$, but this is **not** the case.

According to the limit formula for residues, $Res_R(w)=R(w)$ as long as $w$ is not a pole of $R$, but then of course $Res_R(w)\to\infty$ as $w$ approaches any pole of $R$.  However $Res_R(w)$ is finite everywhere, thus is not continuous at the poles of $R$.  Could someone give an intuitive reason why $Res_R$ is not continuous at the poles of $R$?

Comment: Consider the usual residue of $R(z)$ at $w$ as a function of $w \in \mathbb C$.  This will be $0$ everywhere that $R$ is continuous, and finite but (typically) non-zero at the poles.  Non-rhetorical question: does your intuition also tell you that this should be continuous?

Comment: @Erick Wong That is a good point.  I guess my intuition would be that the residue of $R$ at $w$ **should** be continuous at $w$, while manifestly it is not.  It seems like the entries of the Laurent series for a function should depend continuously on the center of the Laurent series...I guess the problem is just my crappy intuition.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Gamma$ is a simple closed positively-oriented contour, and $f$ is analytic on and inside $\Gamma$, then $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma f(z)\; dz$ is the sum of the residues of the poles of $f$ inside $\Gamma$.  Now in your case for a suitably chosen $\Gamma$, $f(z) = R(z)/(z - w)$ will have two poles inside $\Gamma$, one pole (say $p$) of $R(z)$ and the pole $w$ of $1/(z-w)$ (assuming $w \ne p$).  As you pointed out, as $w$ approaches $p$ both residues get large, 
but their sum stays bounded (as $f(z)$ doesn't change much on $\Gamma$).
However, when $w = p$ we have only one pole inside $\Gamma$, and its residue is
small (again, because $f(z)$ hasn't changed much on $\Gamma$).  The quantity that is continuous is the sum of the residues.